# Deserializing json with recursive types

Tags: json.net

I've got some json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "MenuItem1": [
      { "SubItem1": [ ] },
      { "SubItem2": [ ] },
      { "SubItem3": [ 
          { "SubSubItem": [ ] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "MenuItem2": [ ] }
]
```

This can be represented with the following C# data structure:

```
class MenuItem
{
    Dictionary<string, MenuItem[]> Items;
}
```

I tried deserializing this as

```
MenuItem[] roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem[]>(json);
```

but it doesn't work because it doesn't know that the `Items` member is where this dictionary data is supposed to go on the recursive call.  How can I make this work?

Comment: [Take a look at this site.](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Doesn't help, the nesting can go arbitrarily deep and the depth is variable, so a fixed depth approach won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your JSON does not represent a dictionary of lists of `MenuItem` classes.  Instead, it represents a list of dictionaries of `MenuItem` classes - the reverse of the structure in your data model.

You have several ways you could represent and deserialize this:

1. Define your `MenuItem` as a subclass of a list of dictionaries of `MenuItem` types:

   ```
   public class MenuItem : List<Dictionary<string, MenuItem>>
   {
   }
   ```

   Json.NET will be able to deserialize this as-is out of the box:

   ```
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(json);
   ```
2. Define your `MenuItem` as containing a list of dictionaries of `MenuItem` types:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MenuItemConverter))]
   class MenuItem
   {
       public Dictionary<string, MenuItem> [] Items;
   }
   ```

   You will need a custom converter to bubble the `Items` up one level in the JSON:

   ```
   public class MenuItemConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(MenuItem);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var items = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, MenuItem>[]>(reader);
           return new MenuItem { Items = items };
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var item = (MenuItem)value;
           serializer.Serialize(writer, item.Items);
       }
   }
   ```

   And to deserialize, once again:

   ```
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(json);
   ```
3. If you really want your data model to be a dictionary of lists rather than a list of dictionaries, you will need to restructure your data model as you read and write it:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MenuItemConverter))]
   class MenuItem
   {
       public MenuItem() { this.Items = new Dictionary<string, List<MenuItem>>(); }
       public Dictionary<string, List<MenuItem>> Items;
   }

   public static class DictionaryExtensions
   {
       public static void Add<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
           where TValueList : IList<TValue>, new()
       {
           if (listDictionary == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException();
           TValueList values;
           if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
               listDictionary[key] = values = new TValueList();
           values.Add(value);
       }

       public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
       {
           var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
           dict[key] = value;
           return dict;
       }
   }

   public class MenuItemConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(MenuItem);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var items = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, MenuItem>[]>(reader);
           var menuItem = new MenuItem();
           foreach (var pair in items.SelectMany(d => d))
               menuItem.Items.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
           return menuItem;
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var menuItem = (MenuItem)value;
           if (menuItem.Items == null)
               writer.WriteNull();
           else
           {
               var list = menuItem.Items.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Select(m => DictionaryExtensions.ToDictionary(p.Key, m)));
               serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And then

   ```
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(json);
   ```

Prototype [fiddle showing all three](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uttGeJ).