# Best way to add items to a group dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, grouping

You can do this to group a whole bunch of items at once into a dictionary:

```
var dic = data.GroupBy(data => data.groupID).ToDictionary(gdc => gdc.Key, gdc => gdc.ToList());
```

But what is the best way of adding items to this structure once its created?

I assume just doing this will give a null exception if the group doesn't exist yet:

```
dic[newKey].Add(newItem);
```

So here's the best I've come up with, does it look ok?

```
static Value GetOrAddNew<Key,Value>(Dictionary<Key,Value> dic, Key key) where Value: new() 
{
    Value ans;
    if(!dic.TryGetValue(key, out ans))
    {
        ans = new Value();
        dic.Add(key, ans);
    }
    return ans;
}

void func()
{
    GetOrAddNew(dic,newkey).Add(newItem);
    //or
    GetOrAddNew(dic,newkey).AddRange(newItems);
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  If you're not having any problems with this code then I'm not sure this is on-topic for SO.  Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but read their help pages to be sure.  Only suggestion I'd have is to make it an extension method so you can call it like this `dic.GetOrAddNew(newkey).Add(newItem);`

Comment: should`t you say Value must be a collection of any type so that the outside Add works? i may be reading this wrong, this is a real question tho.

Comment: yes the extension can work too like @juharr said.

Comment: @Zorkind No the `new` will work because `List<T>` has a parameterless constructor.  Then the method returns that list that you can call `Add` on.  If the Dictionary has some other type as the `Value` then obviously `Add` may or may not work based on whatever it is, but the assumption here is that `dic` has lists for values.

Comment: Yes, thats my point, i understood Value is a List, but i wanted to mean: what if its not? shouldt he add a constraint? that`s my question.

Comment: `DictionaryExtensions.AddItem<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>, new()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305109/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964908/3744182) might be what you want.

Comment: @Zorkind Not necessaryily.  Maybe you want to use it with other types.  The result is whatever it creates and then you can do whatever is allowed with that type.  If the value type is a list then you can call `Add` if not you'd do other stuff.

Comment: There`s the constraint hehehe :-P

Comment: Yes @juharr if he want it to be generic, for sure, just thought about his specific scenario in the question hehehe but, yeah ok then :-D